# No repetir datos en MySql con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un proyecto personal con PHP y Mysql. Son mis primeros pasos.
Estoy guardando dos datos mediante un formulario en mi base de datos. Todo funciona correctamente el localhost con xampp. Mi problema viene cuando lo he subido a mi servidor. La conexión con la base de datos es correcta, muestra los datos en el sitio y los guarda correctamente. El problema es que guarda los datos repetidamente, cosa que en local no ocurría.
Este es el codigo de mi archivo registro.php

```
<?php
include './config/conexion.php';

$cantante = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['cantante']));
$cancion = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['cancion']));

    # SQL
    $query = "INSERT INTO datos(cantante, cancion)
              VALUES ('$cantante', '$cancion') ";
    #Verificar que los datos cancion no se repitan en la BD
    $verificar = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE cancion='$cancion'");
    $menu = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12");

   
if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar) == $cancion > 0) {
    #Si existe $cancion no guardar, continuar con la ejecución
 
    
}else {
    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    // eliminar else
    # code...
    
    if ($ejecutar) {
        $ok = "Letra de canción " . $cancion;
    }else{
       
       header('Location: /error.php');
       die();
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
    
}
```

Dicho código guarda los datos correctamente, pero no validad la variable **$cancion** en caso de que se repita. En el caso que se repita debería de seguir la ejecución sin realizar ningun aviso:
`if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar) == $cancion > 0) {`

Y en caso de no existir guardarlo y seguir la ejecución.

Comment: esta condicion: `if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar) == $cancion > 0)`  no parece correcta. estas comparando que "$cancion sea mayor que 0" (es un literal, eso va a dar falso) y luego que el numero de lineas sea igual a falso... si tienes lineas, no sera cierto eso... en teoria con `if (mysqli_num_rows($verificar) > 0)` ya tendrias verificado que existe la linea en tu bbdd. No seria mas sencillo que definieras una clave compuesta en tu bbdd con cantante y cancion? de esta manera solo te preocupas de intentar insertar directamente. Si da error, no se ha podido insertar (porque habra duplicados)

Comment: Concuerdo con lo que te dice @Jakala en su comentario. Además de eso, la mejor manera para saber si un registro existe es ejecutar una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...`  y verificar el resultado que traiga esa consulta. Lo digo porque funciones como `mysqli_num_rows` no son 100% seguras. Por ejemplo, en algunos contextos esa función depende del buffer y puede dar `0` aún cuando haya datos. Otra cosa muy importante es que controles posibles duplicados también, y sobre todo, en la definición de las tablas, creando índices únicos o PK según el caso.

Comment: Existe una función de MySQL llamada llamada ``DISTINCT`` el cual devuelve los valores distintos de la consulta